# Fundamental group of a space where every two points are separated by a "bridge" point

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Consider a (EDIT: Hausdorff) topological space $X$ in which for every two points $x,y\in X$ there exists a "bridge" point $z\in X\setminus\{x,y\}$ such that $x$ and $y$ belong to different connected components of $X\setminus z$.

Is the fundamental group of $X$ trivial?

In my specific case $X$ is path-connected (and thus, I guess, arc-connected), does this help?

EDIT: In my specific case, the space is Hausdorff. At that moment I thought it was implied by the property, but now I see it should be specified.

Comment: For $S^2$ the fundamental group is trivial., For $S^1$ it's not. These are two basic examples.

Comment: @orangeskid I don't see how either of those satisfy the property "for every two points $x,y\in X$ there exists a point $z\in X\setminus\{x,y\}$ such that $x$ and $y$ belong to different connected components of $X\setminus \{z\}$."

Comment: OP:  do you have any examples of such spaces handy (besides things homeo to intervals)?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want spaces with that property... apart from intervals... not sure then

Comment: @Randall Any tree (1-complex). Actually my space is pretty much like a tree: the point $z$ has a 1-dim neighborhood, i.e., is on an "edge" of the "graph". But there can be infinitely many such "edges", and the topology can be more complicated than just a tree.

Comment: I see.  Interesting question.

Comment: @orangeskid I need a proof of that *all* such spaces have trivial fundamental group. Not an example of _some_ such space, which would be any tree.

Comment: @Randall Just the fact that any loop can be "cut" does not help: say, in a path-connected but not arc-connected space, paths can be made "shorter" but not got rid of.

Comment: I see... trees are contractible... is your space too?

Comment: @orangeskid That's what I want to know: is any such space contactible?

Comment: I see... looks like there is essentially just one path between two points ( cannot selfintersect i suppose). Really should be like a hedgehog. Perhaps contractible. Not sure what the topology is on the system of these segments. Is it some infinite simplicial complex? Or more complicated... There at least the topology is compactly generated.

Comment: @orangeskid I suspect it must self-intersect, otherwise the question is rather trivial. Say, in non-arc-connected spaces it must self-intesect. In my case the space is arc-connected, but I don't see how to make use of this fact.

Comment: If a path selfintersects, you cannot have a barrier between coninciding points, since you have a loop between them .

Comment: Or maybe it still can...

Comment: By the way, in the mathematical literature you can find several different classes of such spaces under different names, for example: real trees; dendroids; dendrites (search under all these terms on wikipedia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Hausdoff spaces, the answer is yes, $X$ is simply connected. The answer here uses some continuum theory. The key is to notice that $X$ is uniquely arcwise connected.

First notice that you cannot embed $S^1$ into $X$ because of your required property. This means that $X$ contains no simple closed curves (homeomorphic images of $S^1$). It is well-known that a Hausdorff space $X$ is uniquely arcwise connected if and only if it does not contain a simple closed curve (this might be an exercise in a continuum theory book, e.g. Nadler's book). So $X$ must be uniquely arcwise connected.

Now let $\alpha:(S^1,p)\to (X,x)$ be a loop based at $p$. The image of $S^1$ in a Hausdorff space is a Peano continuum (a path-connected, locally path connected, compact metric space). Moreover $\alpha(S^1)$ must be uniquely arcwise connected since it is a path-connected subspace of a uniquely arcwise connected space. But any uniquely arcwise connected Peano continuum is a dendrite and all dendrites are contractible. Since $\alpha$ factors through a contractible space, it is null-homotopic.

For non-Hausdorff spaces, path connected does not even imply arcwise connected so the result could potentially be false.